# Combine two text in one cell

Tags: excel

In cell A1 I have "B417040028"

I want the 1st word "B" and sixth number "4"  like this "B4"

I want answer like this  "B4"

Comment: BTW, the 6th number is `0` not `4`.  `4` is the 6th character in the string.

Answer (score 3):

parse the string and concatenate:

```
=LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,6,1)
```

[image]